# use selenium and BeautifulSoup scraping dynamic web page but new pages keep poping up

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping content from a dynamic web page. https://www.nytimes.com/search?query=china+COVID-19 I want to get the content of all the news articles (26,783 in total). I cannot iterate pages because on this website you have to click "show more" to load the next page.

Therefore, I'm using webdriver.ActionChians. The code doesn't show any error messages, but every a few seconds a new window would pop up, and it looks like every time it is the same page. This process seems endless, I interrupted it after 2 hours. I used a code "print(article)" but none was displayed.
Could someone help me solve this issue? Much appreciated for the help!

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import string
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
```

```
# Initialize webdriver.Chrome and webdriver.ActionChains only once
chromedriver_path = 'C:/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)

# Get to the page
driver.get('https://www.nytimes.com/search?query=china+COVID-19')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# While button is present
while soup.find('button', {'data-testid': 'search-show-more-button'}) != None:
    # Find button
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="button"][contains(.,"Show More")]')
    # Move to it to avoid false-clicking other elements
    action.move_to_element(button).perform()
    # Click the button
    button.click()
    # Redefine variable 'soup' in case if button dissapeared, so the 'while' loop will end
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')        


search_results = soup.find('ol', {'data-testid':'search-results'})

links = search_results.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    link_url = link['href']

    response = requests.get(base + link_url)
    soup_link = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    scripts = soup_link.find_all('script')
    for script in scripts:
        if 'window.__preloadedData = ' in script.text:
            jsonStr = script.text
            jsonStr = jsonStr.split('window.__preloadedData = ')[-1]
            jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit(';',1)[0]

            jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

            article = []
            for k, v in jsonData['initialState'].items():
                w=1
                try:
                    if v['__typename'] == 'TextInline':
                        article.append(v['text'])
                        #print (v['text'])
                except:
                    continue
            article = [ each.strip() for each in article ]
            article = ''.join([('' if c in string.punctuation else ' ')+c for c in article]).strip()
            print(article)
            myarticle.append(article)


df = pd.DataFrame(myarticle, columns = ['article'])

df.to_csv('NYtimes.csv')

print("Complete")

browser.quit()
```

The output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementClickInterceptedException          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1515a65b3c60> in <module>
     24         try:
---> 25             button.click()
     26             break

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in click(self)
     79         """Clicks the element."""
---> 80         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     81 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button data-testid="search-show-more-button" type="button">...</button> is not clickable at point (509, 656). Other element would receive the click: <div class="css-1n5jm1v">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1515a65b3c60> in <module>
     25             button.click()
     26             break
---> 27         except ElementClickInterceptedException:
     28             time.sleep(0.5)
     29     # Redefine variable 'soup' in case if button dissapeared, so the 'while' loop will end

NameError: name 'ElementClickInterceptedException' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'new window' pops up because you recreate the driver each loop's iteration.

Step by step. Firstly you create driver here and get to the page:

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.nytimes.com/search?query=china+COVID-19')
```

Then inside the loop you create one more driver each iteration:

```py
while True:
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get('https://www.nytimes.com/search?query=china+COVID-19')
```

This is why you see new window each time.

To fix this, you can apply this code (this includes only iteration part):

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Initialize webdriver.Chrome and webdriver.ActionChains only once
chromedriver_path = 'C:/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)

# Get to the page
driver.get('https://www.nytimes.com/search?query=china+COVID-19')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# While button is present
while soup.find('button', {'data-testid': 'search-show-more-button'}) != None:
    # Find button
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="button"][contains(.,"Show More")]')
    # Move to it to avoid false-clicking other elements
    action.move_to_element(button).perform()
    # Movement takes some time and not instant, therefore it is better to add a short wait
    # to make sure that ElementClickInterceptedException won't appear
    time.sleep(0.5)
    # However, constant time sleep is not reliable if something unexpected happened and more
    # time was required, therefore let's just create an endless loop, which will break once
    # 'click' was successful. According to your last error, the 'covering element' was a 'div'.
    # In other words, even by false-clicking you won't cause any action, which is why this
    # solution is save.
    while True:
        try:
            button.click()
            break
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            time.sleep(0.5)
    # Redefine variable 'soup' in case if button dissapeared, so the 'while' loop will end
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

As far as I got, there wasn't any question about second part, where you are parsing search results, but if you have some, feel free to ask.

UPD: there is also no sense in initializing ActionChains each iteration, so you can do this right after creation of webdriver. (I've changed code sample, so you can simply copy and read comments on each step)

UPD2: I added some additional protection to avoid false-clicking.

Comment: Thank you very much! The comments are very clear! I used this code, but I got an error message: " Message: element click intercepted: Element <button data-testid="search-show-more-button" type="button">...</button> is not clickable at point (509, 658)". Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: Sure, it means that webdriver wasn't able to click on 'Show more' button, because another element was 'covering' it. Could you please rerun the code and send me full error. Commonly, after the part you already sent, there is a mentioning of the 'covering' element, so I can find it an update the code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I added the full error in the description, and updated the code that I'm using (just a combination of your code and the rest of my code).

Comment: Hi again, please check the updated code. You can also remove comments from your production code, since they take a lot of space :)

Comment: Thank you. But the code still doesn't work. I updated the error message in the description. Oh, I also want to ask the remaining part should with four spaces indent or without?

Comment: Hello, to fix your last error, just add 'from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException' at the start. As far as I see, you just eventually forgot to add this, it's okay :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214528/discussion-between-maliarov-and-yue-peng).